# Upload picture to twitter from iPhone

Tags: iphone, upload, twitter, twitpic

Is it possible to programmatically upload a picture to twitter from iPhone?

Can this be done through twitter directly, or do I need to use a third-party service like Twitpic?

Comment: Added the magic word: "programmatically".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for editing your question. It makes more sense now. I'm leaving my original answer up so that this thread doesn't become confusing.

Anyway, the answer is short: the Twitter API doesn't provide a way for you to upload a photo directly with a status update, so I'm fairly certain you need to use a third-party service. The official Twitter client uses yFrog by default, but it lets you change the service to TwitPic, TweetPhoto, Mobypicture, Twitgoo, Posterous, img.ly, or a custom service.

Answer (score 2):

Just use http://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine.

Comment: @Hi gurpartrap the link you provide is very good but there is one problem that in this line [twitpicEngine setAccessToken:token]; whet does token mean? , means what should I pass here.Please tell as I am stuck here.

Comment: hi @Gurpartap Singh. i have check the above link and made one demo with importing all required file .. it is build successfully. i have made one simple demo to check this and write down code in viewDidload() to upload image . but not working .. there is no any login screen than how can i make this possible ? plz suggest me

Comment: Uses the no longer supported but much missed ASIHTTPRequest.